# customizing writeToFile in objectiveC

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm interested in customizing the writeToFile method so that I can generate an XML document with a particular schema.

Is there an accepted/recommended way of doing this?

Any and all pointers are appreciated!

Comment: 0xFFF1E3A0(hey you said pointers were appreciated ;))

Comment: Make yourself a subclass of NSObject with the preferred instance variables. If someone calls - (NSData *)XMLData then create an NSXMLDocument and return its data.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are interested in general file I/O, in which case you might be interested in a link like [this](http://maccoder.blogspot.com/2007/02/reading-and-writing-data-using.html).  You will not likely be "customizing" writeToFile, since the way you assemble XML data will probably be with NSString or NSData on an iPhone, which already have the I/O methods you need.

If you don't mind being abstracted away from the actual bits and bytes of I/O, you could try a third party XML package like [this](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/index.html), which can write out an XML document, once you have specified it using the API.

The comment by lef2 is for Mac, not for iPhone.